# BigQuery use 2 pivots for 2 columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot

I have this table:

| key | value | team | number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| score | 35 | team | 5 |

and I want to create the above table:

| score | team |
| --- | --- |
| 35 | 5 |

meaning I want to make 2 pivots. Is there a way to do it in one query?

the following code doesn't work in bigquery:

```
with a as(
select 'score' as key, 35 as value, 'team' as team, 5 as number
)

select *
from a
pivot (any_value(value) for key in ('score'))
pivot (any_value(number) for team in ('team'))
```

Answer (score 0):

See simple fix below

```
select * from (
  select * from your_table
  pivot (any_value(value) for key in ('score'))
)
pivot (any_value(number) for team in ('team'))
```

with output like below

[image]